# Android: динамическое добавление элементов таблицы

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. Начал изучать JAVA и сейчас решаю вот такую задачу.

В бассейне 1 000 000 литров воды. Каждый день из бассейна откачивается вода насосом производительностью 50 000 л/день. Помимо этого, вода в количестве 5% от остатка на вчерашний день, утекает через трещину в стенке бассейна. Требуется построить таблицу с данными (в каждой строке):

1. День номер...
2. Откачано насосом
3. Утекло через трещину
4. Всего воды утрачено
5. Осталось в бассейне

Как это лучше всего реализовать? Пожалуйста, объясните. Мне нужен не готовый код, а объяснение с примером.

Comment: Поясни что не получается, с какими таблицами работаешь .... за просто поставленную задачу обычно минусуют и таки правы ) В чем конкретно проблема с реализацией в для андроида, или алгоритм java? в вопросе увидел только постановку задачи.

Comment: Нужен алгоритм JAVA

Вот файл разметки таблицы main.xml

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TableLayout>


Файл разметки строки таблицы


<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView 
 android:text=""
 android:id="@+id/number"/>
 
    <TextView
 android:text=""
 android:id="@+id/pump"/>
 
 ...
 
</TableRow>


Необходимо создавать экземпляр строки с помощью LayoutInflater и добавлять его в TableLayout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если рассматривать реализацию этой задачи в Android, то нам понадобится одна активити, в разметке которой имеется таблица, которую мы будем заполнять результатами расчётов.

Начнём с разметки активити res/layout/main.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TableLayout>
```

Здесь у нас единственный элемент таблицы TableLayout, в него мы будем добавлять строки с результатами вычислений программно. Чтобы обратиться из кода к элементу мы присвоили ему идентификатор [@id](/users/11054/idd)/table.

Далее создаём разметку строки таблицы res/layout/table_row.xml:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/col1" android:text="" />
  <TextView android:id="@+id/col2" android:text="" />
  <TextView android:id="@+id/col3" android:text="" />
  <TextView android:id="@+id/col4" android:text="" />
  <TextView android:id="@+id/col5" android:text="" />
  <TextView android:id="@+id/col6" android:text="" />
</TableRow>
```

Это у нас будет шаблон строки таблицы с шестью столбцами. Для помещения значения в ячейки строки всем ячейкам присвоены идентификаторы.

Теперь создаём саму активити src/TableActivity.java:

```
public class TableActivity extends Activity {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  //Указываем созданную нами ранее разметку
    int totalWater = 1000000; //Начальный объем бассейна
    int dayNum = 0; //Счётчик дней
    int pumped = 0; //Сколько откачано насосом
    int flowed = 0; //Сколько утекло
    int lost = 0; //Сколько всего утрачено
    //Используем цикл, в котором будем рассчитывать значения для нашей таблицы, пока вода в бассейне не закончится
    while (totalWater > 0) {
      day++; //Счётчик дней увеличиваем в начале цикла, т.к. начальное значение у него 0
      //Вычисление всех значений оставляю на совести автора, т.к. это математика для 5 класса
      ...
      //Будем считать, что к этой строке все значения для текущего дня уже вычислены
      //Передаём в метод добавления строки вычисленные значения
      addRow(dayNum, pumped, flowed, lost, totalWater);
    }
  }

  public void addRow(int c0, int c1, int c2, int c3, int c4, int c5) {
    //Сначала найдем в разметке активити саму таблицу по идентификатору
    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    //Создаём экземпляр инфлейтера, который понадобится для создания строки таблицы из шаблона. В качестве контекста у нас используется сама активити
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    //Создаем строку таблицы, используя шаблон из файла /res/layout/table_row.xml
    TableRow tr = (TableRow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);
    //Находим ячейку для номера дня по идентификатору
    TextView tv = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.col1);
    //Обязательно приводим число к строке, иначе оно будет воспринято как идентификатор ресурса
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(c0));
    //Ищем следующую ячейку и устанавливаем её значение
    tv = (TextView) tr.findViewById(R.id.col1);
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(c1));
    //...и так далее для всех значений
    tableLayout.addView(tr); //добавляем созданную строку в таблицу
  }
}
```

Как-то так. Как еще подробнее я уж не знаю...

Comment: а почему не адаптером?

Comment: Вопрос стоял про TableLayout. А вообще да, можно и ListView с адаптером использовать...

Comment: Эклипс ругается на строку 

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.fromContext(this);

Ошибка: The method fromContext(TableActivity) is undefined for the type LayoutInflater

Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Ну да, тут я немного ошибся. У LayoutInflater нет метода fromContext(), зато есть метод from(). В документацию заглядывайте иногда...

Answer (score -2):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(0);
```

Через `ID` работать не выйдет.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?